# A kernel on the d-dimensional flat torus with smoothing properties in the $L^{\infty}$-norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $\rho: \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be smooth, symmetric, of compact support, and satisfy $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\rho(x)dx=1$. For each $\epsilon>0$, set $\rho_{\epsilon}(x)=\epsilon^{-d}\rho(\epsilon^{-1}x)$.

Denote by $W^{m,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $m\in \mathbf{N}\cup \{0\}$, the Sobolev spaces ($p=\infty$).

It is straightforward to check that for all $n\in \{0,1,2\}$ there is a constant $C=C(n)>0$ such that for all  $\epsilon>0$ and $m\in \mathbf{N}\cup \{0\}$, 
$$
|\rho_{\epsilon}*f|_{W^{m+n,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)}\le C \epsilon^{-n}|f|_{W^{m,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)}
, \quad \forall f\in W^{m,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d),$$
and
$$
|f-\rho_{\epsilon} *f|_{W^{m,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)}\le C \epsilon^n | f|_{W^{m+n,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)}, \quad  \forall f\in W^{m+n,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d).
$$
To prove the first fact one uses integration by parts  and that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \partial^{\gamma}_x \rho_{\epsilon}(x-y)dx\le C\epsilon^{|\gamma|},
$$
for all multi-indices $\gamma$ with $|\gamma|\le 2$.
To prove the second fact one uses Taylor's formula, that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}y\rho_{\epsilon}(y)=0$, and that 
$$
\quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|y|^n\rho_{\epsilon}(y)dy\le C\epsilon^n, \quad \forall n\in \{0,1,2\}.
$$

I am interested in an analogous result for the $d$-dimensional flat torus $\mathbb{T}^d=\mathbb{R}^d/(2\pi \mathbb{Z}^d)$.

Denote by $W^{m,\infty}(\mathbb{T}^d)$, $m\in \mathbf{N}\cup \{0\}$, the Sobolev spaces ($p=\infty$).

Does there exist  a sequence of functions $\{K_N\}_{N\in \mathbf{N}^d}$, on $\mathbb{T}^d$ such that for all $n\in \{0,1,2\}$ there is a constant $C=C(n)>0$ such that for all $N\in \mathbf{N}^d$ and $m\in \mathbf{N}\cup \{0\}$, 
$$
|K_{N}*f|_{W^{m+n,\infty}(\mathbb{T}^d)}\le C |N|^n|f|_{W^{m,\infty}(\mathbb{T}^d)}, \quad   \forall f\in W^{m,\infty}(\mathbb{T}^d),
$$
and
$$
|f-K_N *f|_{ W^{m,\infty}(\mathbb{T}^d)}\le C |N|^{-n} | f|_{W^{m+n,\infty}(\mathbb{T}^d)},  \quad   \forall f\in W^{m+n,\infty}(\mathbb{T}^d)?
$$
For instance, does the Fejer kernel satisfy the above properties?